# Can't get Video Demo List Activity Feature from youtube /Android APi to integrate with a test app -Help Really needed

Tags: android, listview, youtube

I am trying to integrate the VideoDemoListActivity Demo/Feature from Youtube/Androids API into an android app.  I am a newbie to both Java and Android - this is my first question here! I have managed to find and install the sample  from the youtube android api's.   I have extended  VideoListDemoActivity by FragmentActivity, I have renamed  the fragment id's from the xml files to point to the test site, included the activity  in the Manifest XML and linked a tab to display. However, there are no errors showing  in eclipse and when I go to run I get FATAL EXCEPTION main amongst other errors in the logcat.

Note, I reconfigured my emulator to show video etc, so I can't see it being the emulator as the whole api plays etc.

Here's the code for the java class

```
@TargetApi(13)
public final class VideoListDemoActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnFullscreenListener {

  /** The duration of the animation sliding up the video in portrait. */
  private static final int ANIMATION_DURATION_MILLIS = 300;
  /** The padding between the video list and the video in landscape orientation. */
  private static final int LANDSCAPE_VIDEO_PADDING_DP = 5;

  private VideoListFragment listFragment;
  private VideoFragment videoFragment;

  private View videoBox;
  private View closeButton;

  private boolean isFullscreen;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.video_list_demo);

    listFragment = (VideoListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.list_fragment);
    videoFragment =
        (VideoFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.video_fragment_container);

    videoBox = findViewById(R.id.video_box);
    closeButton = findViewById(R.id.close_button);

    videoBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    layout();
  }

  @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    layout();
  }

  @Override
  public void onFullscreen(boolean isFullscreen) {
    this.isFullscreen = isFullscreen;

    layout();
  }

  /**
   * Sets up the layout programatically for the three different states. Portrait, landscape or
   * fullscreen+landscape. This has to be done programmatically because we handle the orientation
   * changes ourselves in order to get fluent fullscreen transitions, so the xml layout resources
   * do not get reloaded.
   */
  private void layout() {
    boolean isPortrait =
        getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

    listFragment.getView().setVisibility(isFullscreen ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    listFragment.setLabelVisibility(isPortrait);
    closeButton.setVisibility(isPortrait ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

    if (isFullscreen) {
      videoBox.setTranslationY(0); // Reset any translation that was applied in portrait.
      setLayoutSize(videoFragment.getView(), MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);
      setLayoutSizeAndGravity(videoBox, MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT);
    } else if (isPortrait) {
      setLayoutSize(listFragment.getView(), MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);
      setLayoutSize(videoFragment.getView(), MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
      setLayoutSizeAndGravity(videoBox, MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM);
    } else {
      videoBox.setTranslationY(0); // Reset any translation that was applied in portrait.
      int screenWidth = dpToPx(getResources().getConfiguration().screenWidthDp);
      setLayoutSize(listFragment.getView(), screenWidth / 4, MATCH_PARENT);
      int videoWidth = screenWidth - screenWidth / 4 - dpToPx(LANDSCAPE_VIDEO_PADDING_DP);
      setLayoutSize(videoFragment.getView(), videoWidth, WRAP_CONTENT);
      setLayoutSizeAndGravity(videoBox, videoWidth, WRAP_CONTENT,
          Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    }
  }

  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void onClickClose(@SuppressWarnings("unused") View view) {
    listFragment.getListView().clearChoices();
    listFragment.getListView().requestLayout();
    videoFragment.pause();
    videoBox.animate()
        .translationYBy(videoBox.getHeight())
        .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MILLIS)
        .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            videoBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          }
        });
  }

  /**
   * A fragment that shows a static list of videos.
   */
  public static final class VideoListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private static final List<VideoEntry> VIDEO_LIST;
    static {
      List<VideoEntry> list = new ArrayList<VideoEntry>();
      list.add(new VideoEntry("YouTube Collection", "Y_UmWdcTrrc"));
      list.add(new VideoEntry("GMail Tap", "1KhZKNZO8mQ"));
      list.add(new VideoEntry("Chrome Multitask", "UiLSiqyDf4Y"));
      list.add(new VideoEntry("Google Fiber", "re0VRK6ouwI"));
      list.add(new VideoEntry("Autocompleter", "blB_X38YSxQ"));
      list.add(new VideoEntry("GMail Motion", "Bu927_ul_X0"));
      list.add(new VideoEntry("Translate for Animals", "3I24bSteJpw"));
      VIDEO_LIST = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
    }

    private PageAdapter adapter;
    private View videoBox;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      adapter = new PageAdapter(getActivity(), VIDEO_LIST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

      videoBox = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.video_box);
      getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
      setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
      String videoId = VIDEO_LIST.get(position).videoId;

      VideoFragment videoFragment =
          (VideoFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.video_fragment_container);
      videoFragment.setVideoId(videoId);

      // The videoBox is INVISIBLE if no video was previously selected, so we need to show it now.
      if (videoBox.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
          // Initially translate off the screen so that it can be animated in from below.
          videoBox.setTranslationY(videoBox.getHeight());
        }
        videoBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }

      // If the fragment is off the screen, we animate it in.
      if (videoBox.getTranslationY() > 0) {
        videoBox.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MILLIS);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
      super.onDestroyView();

      adapter.releaseLoaders();
    }

    public void setLabelVisibility(boolean visible) {
      adapter.setLabelVisibility(visible);
    }

  }

  /**
   * Adapter for the video list. Manages a set of YouTubeThumbnailViews, including initializing each
   * of them only once and keeping track of the loader of each one. When the ListFragment gets
   * destroyed it releases all the loaders.
   */
  private static final class PageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final List<VideoEntry> entries;
    private final List<View> entryViews;
    private final Map<YouTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader> thumbnailViewToLoaderMap;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final ThumbnailListener thumbnailListener;

    private boolean labelsVisible;

    public PageAdapter(Context context, List<VideoEntry> entries) {
      this.entries = entries;

      entryViews = new ArrayList<View>();
      thumbnailViewToLoaderMap = new HashMap<YouTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader>();
      inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      thumbnailListener = new ThumbnailListener();

      labelsVisible = true;
    }

    public void releaseLoaders() {
      for (YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader : thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.values()) {
        loader.release();
      }
    }

    public void setLabelVisibility(boolean visible) {
      labelsVisible = visible;
      for (View view : entryViews) {
        view.findViewById(R.id.text).setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return entries.size();
    }

    @Override
    public VideoEntry getItem(int position) {
      return entries.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
      return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View view = convertView;
      VideoEntry entry = entries.get(position);

      // There are three cases here
      if (view == null) {
        // 1) The view has not yet been created - we need to initialize the YouTubeThumbnailView.
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_list_item, parent, false);
        YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail = (YouTubeThumbnailView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        thumbnail.setTag(entry.videoId);
        thumbnail.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, thumbnailListener);
      } else {
        YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail = (YouTubeThumbnailView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader = thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.get(thumbnail);
        if (loader == null) {
          // 2) The view is already created, and is currently being initialized. We store the
          //    current videoId in the tag.
          thumbnail.setTag(entry.videoId);
        } else {
          // 3) The view is already created and already initialized. Simply set the right videoId
          //    on the loader.
          thumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading_thumbnail);
          loader.setVideo(entry.videoId);
        }
      }
      TextView label = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text));
      label.setText(entry.text);
      label.setVisibility(labelsVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
      return view;
    }

    private final class ThumbnailListener implements
        YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener,
        YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener {

      @Override
      public void onInitializationSuccess(
          YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader) {
        loader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(this);
        thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.put(view, loader);
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading_thumbnail);
        String videoId = (String) view.getTag();
        loader.setVideo(videoId);
      }

      @Override
      public void onInitializationFailure(
          YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeInitializationResult loader) {
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_thumbnail);
      }

      @Override
      public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView view, String videoId) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView view, ErrorReason errorReason) {
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_thumbnail);
      }
    }

  }

  public static final class VideoFragment extends YouTubePlayerFragment
      implements OnInitializedListener {

    private YouTubePlayer player;
    private String videoId;

    public static VideoFragment newInstance() {
      return new VideoFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
      if (player != null) {
        player.release();
      }
      super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void setVideoId(String videoId) {
      if (videoId != null && !videoId.equals(this.videoId)) {
        this.videoId = videoId;
        if (player != null) {
          player.cueVideo(videoId);
        }
      }
    }

    public void pause() {
      if (player != null) {
        player.pause();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean restored) {
      this.player = player;
      player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);
      player.setOnFullscreenListener((VideoListDemoActivity) getActivity());
      if (!restored && videoId != null) {
        player.cueVideo(videoId);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
      this.player = null;
    }

  }

  private static final class VideoEntry {
    private final String text;
    private final String videoId;

    public VideoEntry(String text, String videoId) {
      this.text = text;
      this.videoId = videoId;
    }
  }

  // Utility methods for layouting.

  private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    return (int) (dp * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
  }

  private static void setLayoutSize(View view, int width, int height) {
    LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = width;
    params.height = height;
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
  }

  private static void setLayoutSizeAndGravity(View view, int width, int height, int gravity) {
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = width;
    params.height = height;
    params.gravity = gravity;
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
  }

}
```

the xml files

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--
  Copyright 2012 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

  <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
      android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:src="@drawable/no_thumbnail"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
      android:textColor="#fff"/>

</LinearLayout>


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--
  Copyright 2012 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <fragment
      class="com.tst1.lister.VideoListDemoActivity$VideoListFragment"
      android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/video_box"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/close_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"
        android:onClick="onClickClose"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/video_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.tst1.lister.VideoListDemoActivity$VideoFragment" />

  </LinearLayout>

</merge>
```

The manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tst1.lister"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">

        <activity android:name=".about" />
        <activity android:name=".video" />
        <activity android:name=".more" />



        <activity
            android:name="com.tst1.lister.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="@string/isLaunchableActivity" android:value="false"/>
        </activity>


    <activity
        android:label="@string/videolist_demo_name"
        android:name=".VideoListDemoActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
      <meta-data android:name="@string/minVersion" android:value="13"/>
      <meta-data android:name="@string/isLaunchableActivity" android:value="true"/>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:label="@string/playerview_demo_name"
        android:name=".PlayerViewDemoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
      <meta-data android:name="@string/minVersion" android:value="8"/>
      <meta-data android:name="@string/isLaunchableActivity" android:value="true"/>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:label="@string/fragment_demo_name"
        android:name=".FragmentDemoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
      <meta-data android:name="@string/minVersion" android:value="11"/>
      <meta-data android:name="@string/isLaunchableActivity" android:value="true"/>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:label="@string/player_controls_demo_name"
        android:name=".PlayerControlsDemoActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
      <meta-data android:name="@string/minVersion" android:value="8"/>
      <meta-data android:name="@string/isLaunchableActivity" android:value="true"/>
    </activity>



    <activity
        android:label="@string/standalone_player_demo_name"
        android:name=".StandalonePlayerDemoActivity">
      <meta-data android:name="@string/minVersion" android:value="8"/>
      <meta-data android:name="@string/isLaunchableActivity" android:value="true"/>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:label="@string/intents_demo_name"
        android:name=".IntentsDemoActivity">
      <meta-data android:name="@string/minVersion" android:value="8"/>
      <meta-data android:name="@string/isLaunchableActivity" android:value="true"/>
    </activity>

  </application>



</manifest>
```

Log Cat

```
    05-10 21:25:05.711: I/(3162): Video Item Clicked
    05-10 21:25:05.910: D/AndroidRuntime(3162): Shutting down VM
05-10 21:25:05.910: W/dalvikvm(3162): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tst1.lister/com.tst1.lister.VideoListDemoActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:459)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at com.tst1.lister.VideoListDemoActivity.onCreate(VideoListDemoActivity.java:68)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     ... 11 more
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.tst1.lister.VideoListDemoActivity$VideoListFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:394)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
05-10 21:25:05.960: E/AndroidRuntime(3162):     ... 21 more
05-10 21:30:06.060: I/Process(3162): Sending signal. PID: 3162 SIG: 9
05-10 21:30:06.830: E/Trace(3177): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-10 21:30:07.860: D/gralloc_goldfish(3177): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Comment: As Youtube documentation says: "Users need to run version 4.2.16 of the mobile YouTube app (or higher) to use the API.". So running tests on android emulator that dont have youtube app with required version fails to run.

Comment: Looks like something is wrong in your xml file. It says `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22:` These kinds of errors often won't show until runtime and won't show in the xml file itself. Double check your xml.

Answer (score 0):

I am also a noob, but I've gotten the list.

For more information I copy this [code](https://github.com/youtube/yt-android-player)

You can also visit [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189063/tabhost-youtube-player-list-api-implicit-intents-with-startservice-are-not-s) there is left a piece of code Tab1Activity.java with everything needed for the list

Comment: Better to leave a brief explanation here, and reference to the link for details.